# I there a function to divide the values in one vector with values in another?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have two vectors, this.position and grid.dimensions. I know you can't divide vectors but I would like to do something like

```
let gridCell = createVector(this.position.x / grid.dimensions.x, this.position.y / grid.dimensions.y)
```

Is there some way to do this? I tried:

```
let gridCell = p5.Vector.div(this.position, grid.dimensions),
```

but this .div only accepts values.

Comment: There is no such function specified in the documentation - see [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector). So you've to declare your own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a function in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) that does what you want. I think your best option is to come up with your own solution.

Your first code snippet lets fine to me. You could put that into a function so you don't have to clutter up your code with it, but that's a minor detail.